# Upgrading from 5.32 to 5.47

Tags: upgrade

Are there any issues with going straight from 5.32 to 5.47? Sorry for the direct question, I'm still learning how CiviCRM works.

Answer (score 4):

It should be straightforward. In case you have the Grant component enabled then it would make it complicated as the Grant is now moved into an extension and many of us are facing issues while doing the upgrade.

Having said that you need to backup your site before proceeding with the upgrade.

Comment: i think there have also been some cautionary notes about civicrm_entity tripping the upgrade up

Comment: Hi Pete, Do you have any details about it?

Comment: A new release just came out - believe it related to the CiviGrant being moved in to an extension, and perhaps C_E was still expecting it to be a Component

Comment: Yeah, it's the same thing with the extended report. Is there any discussion going on?

Comment: Just want to add that the Grant extension implementation is a disaster IMHO. One case in point -- things like grant statuses are handled with managed files. If your installation has any modifications to existing values (adding, renaming, etc.), you're going to hit tons of managed entity errors that are not trivial to sort through. I think we need to really rethink how we handle something like this. The managed entity model is very problematic in certain contexts.